# how ngIf works is it much faster than hidden attribute?

Tags: angular

I was just thinking how ngif works. Since the tag has to be specified in the html file and it will be loaded when the component is visible. Angular decides render/not after the whole element is loaded in the dom? Is it a lot faster than hidden when renders?

Comment: If ngIf results into false it actually does not show up in the DOM, while tags with a hidden attribute do.

Answer (score 1):

ngIf only creates the element in the DOM if true. ngShow always creates the element in the DOM, but just show/hide it. So unless you have some functionality that requires the element to always exist in the DOM to be accessed, then you should use ngIf, to make the DOM more light and more performent.

Comment: I guess angular doesn't just attach partial html page to the dom but it loads into the memory and attach to the dom while analyze the element.

Answer (score 1):

> `*ngIf` removes it completely from the DOM, meanwhile hidden attribute is just setting a `display: none` style to the element (it's in the DOM but hidden).

Both are the same in terms of performance, becouse both are angular common atributes `(*ngIf === [ngIf])` and they work equal at angular rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Another important point with *ngIf is that when the condition turns to false, the ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook gets called, and when the condition turns to true again, ngOnInit lifecycle hook gets called again and so on. So you might want to pay attention to that too.

Answer (score 0):

**ngIf** is structural directive that, in case expression is true, renders part of the DOM.
On the other hand, **hidden** attribute doesn't remove element from DOM, it still exists, but it doesn't show it.